# How to get number of web hits for a given query?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-applications, information-retrieval

I'm doing a project based on information retrieval, in that i want to know how many web hits for a given query on the web. Is it possible to get web hits from google?? if so , can any body tell me how to get web hits using a java program??

Comment: Web hit? Can you elaborate what you mean by this?

Comment: In my project i need to find the association between the given name and it's alias.Here web hit refers to no of pages they both appear together in overall web.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/). You can find out the trend of a particular query and download the results as CSV.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get that CSV. i'm new to google API's.

Comment: I haven't looked into doing it through the API. There is a download link once you enter a search term into the trends page.